# After leaving URL and coming back data is missing from Chart. Upon refresh, it shows

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-visualization

My application is showing the data in the chart without issue upon the first page load... however when I leave the page and click on a navbar route and come back, the data is no longer showing. I can see the request coming through successfully in the console. If I refresh the page (CMD+R) the data and chart shows again.

```
import { Component, OnInit, wtfCreateScope } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from 'src/app/shared/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ticket-by-status',
  templateUrl: './ticket-by-status.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ticket-by-status.component.css']
})
export class TicketByStatusComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service: UserService) { }

  title = 'Tickets by Status';
  type = 'PieChart';
  data = [];
  columnNames = ['Ticket', 'Percentage'];
  options = {};
  width = 1600;
  height = 600;

  ngOnInit() {

    this.service.getNewTickets().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.data.push(['New', +res])
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    ),
    this.service.getOpenTickets().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.data.push(['Open', +res])
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    ),
    this.service.getPendingTickets().subscribe(
      res => {
       this.data.push(['Pending', +res])
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    ),
    this.service.getSolvedTickets().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.data.push(['Solved', +res])
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Here is an example of getNewTickets

```
  getNewTickets(){
    return this.http.get(this.BaseUri+'/tickets/status/count/New', this.httpOptions)
  }
```

I will likely refactor these to accept a parameter and pass in 'New', 'Solved', etc. later. For now, the focus is this chart.

Here's the HTML:

```
<google-chart #chart  
   [title]="title"  
   [type]="type"  
   [data]="data"  
   [columnNames]="columnNames"  
   [options]="options"  
   [width]="width"  
   [height]="height">  
</google-chart>
```

Comment: Can you pack your example into a stackblitz or something..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the best solution, but you can try to add *ngIf="data.length > 0" to your google-chart call.

Comment: *ngIf="data.length > 3" gets the data showing, when I do > 1 I only get 1 result. In this case, there will always be 4 results so it technically works, but it feels dirty haha.